# Where is the source code in Android's BLE stack that handles the internal transmission buffer?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to investigate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741849/oncharacteristicwrite-and-onnotificationsent-are-being-called-too-fast-how-to/43744888#43744888) comment from StackOverflow regarding Android's handling of the internal BLE transmission buffer. Where can I find the source code that is referenced by the answer?